# [SalesForce]Wrap text CSS not work with render pdf in Salesforce

Tags: css

i have to input a very long text into  tag, and i use this CSS :

```
.wrapword{
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  
        white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; 
        white-space: -pre-wrap;     
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   
        white-space: pre-wrap;     
        word-wrap: break-word;      
        word-break: break-all;
        white-space: normal;
        -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
        }
```

Ofcourse  table-layout : fixed.
In html form, this CSS work OK. But when i render page into pdf by using renderAs="pdf" of Salesforce, wrap-textCSS not work.
Is there any body tell me why? :(

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution for this issue? i am facing same issue let me know if you found something.